# matplotlib choose between 2 color scheme or 3 color scheme

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a plot of values sampled from the set [ -1, 0, 1] and each value is mapped to a color. However it is possible to have a sample where only two different values appear ( [-1,0], [-1,1], [0,1] ) and if that happens, then the color scheme should adapt accordingly

If the number of unique values is 3, then this code works

```
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((n_rows , 1), (2, 0))
colors = [(216/255, 24/255, 24/255), (1, 1, 1), (143/255, 188/255, 143/255)]    
positions = df['long'].astype(int) - df['short'].astype(int)
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycols', colors, N=3)
ax2.pcolorfast(ax2.get_xlim(), ax2.get_ylim(),  positions.values[np.newaxis], cmap=cm, alpha=0.5)
```

The result is

[image]

How should I manage the scenarios where only two colors are needed?

I think this controls the number of segments, but I don't know how to account for the color scheme

```
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('colores', colors, N=len(list(set(positions))))
```

Comment: Usually you wouldn't create a different colormap, but change the normalization or even only the values. It's hard to give a useful answer here because it's unclear how you *use* the colormap to create your plot. If you want to provide a [mcve], that would sure be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to use the same colours, in the same order, from the current scheme (which would be red-white for just two values)?

Comment: @9769953 the mapping should be [red, white, green] for [-1, 0, 1]. So if there's only [-1, 0] then plot in red and white. If there's only [-1,1] then plot only red and green

Comment: No, I meant what it should be for two colours. Or does that depend on the available values?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm aware that I don't provide data because I can't figure out a way to provide it efficiently and completely. If it is unclear then ask me a question so I can be more explicit

Comment: The question is as stated above already: how do you use the colormap to create your plot?

Comment: @9769953 I edited my response in the comments :)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited my question, I see your point now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make colors a numpy array, you could do something along these lines: `colors[np.isin([-1, 0, 1], sorted(available_values))]` to select just the wanted colours. The `[-1, 0, 1]` should of course be a complete list of all available values, with a one to one correspondence with `colors`.

Note that this may not work when the values are floating point values, since the comparison will not be accurate at times.

Example code (untested):

```
all_values = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
colors = np.array([(216/255, 24/255, 24/255), (1, 1, 1), (143/255, 188/255, 143/255)])
positions = df['long'].astype(int) - df['short'].astype(int)
available_values = set(positions)
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycols', colors[np.isin(all_values, sorted(available_values))], N=len(available_values))
ax2.pcolorfast(ax2.get_xlim(), ax2.get_ylim(),  positions.values[np.newaxis], cmap=cm, alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: tested it, and it works. Accepting answer since it was the first, but the other is prettier lol

Comment: @Yuca It's not about being first, or being the prettiest (unless either of those are a requirement of the question), but what works best for you. My answer stays close to your own code and attempted solution, while the other answer adds something to show how things could be differently (which could be more generic for other readers).

Comment: I know it is not about that, but since both answers work for me the only criterion left is time order. However, if the StackOverflow guideline is to favor the more general answer, then I'll change my mark

Answer (score 1):

Usually one would not create new colormap for each plot with different values, but rather change the normalization.

Here, as I understand it, there are only ever the values `[-1,0,1]` or any subset of those in use. Hence one may use a single normalization as `plt.Normalize(-1,1)` throughout.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np


colors = [(216/255., 24/255., 24/255.), (1., 1., 1.), (143/255., 188/255., 143/255.)]
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
norm=plt.Normalize(-1,1)

combinations = [[-1,0,1],[-1,0],[0,1],[-1,1]]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(combinations), sharex=True)

for combo, ax in zip(combinations, axes):    
    data = np.random.choice(combo, size=(50))

    ax.pcolorfast(np.atleast_2d(data), cmap=cmap, norm=norm, alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_ylabel(combo)

plt.show()
```

[image]